# AngularJS -- View Will Not Render in my Browser?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I am navigating to a route '/login' I set up in my angular app.  When I try to navigate to the view I created, using angular routing, I only see the navbar on my page, and nothing inside ng-view.  In the network tab of my chrome console, it shows that the view is being successfully requested and sent to the client, yet it is not rendering for me in view source.  Also I'd like to note that my route for '/' is working correcting. There are no errors in the console.

I am using NodeJS + ExpressJS for my webserver.  It's an SPA.  Also I am using RequireJS for module loading.

**server.js**

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    path = require('path'),
    apiRouter = require('./app/routes/api'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    compression = require('compression');

app.use(compression());
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use('/api', apiRouter);

app.use('*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/public/index.html'));
});

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/triviaattack');

var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function() {
    //Connected to DB successfully.

});

app.listen(1337);
```

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="apple-touch-icon.png">
        <!-- Place favicon.ico in the root directory -->

        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
        <!-- <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3.min.js"></script> -->
        <script data-main="js/main" src="js/vendor/require.js"></script>     
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--[if lt IE 8]>
            <p class="browserupgrade">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
        <![endif]-->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" ng-controller="navCtrl">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><button class="btn btn-default navbar-btn" ng-click="login()">Login</button></li>
                <li><button class="btn btn-info navbar-btn" ng-click="register()">Register</button></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!--/.navbar-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>
        <div ng-view></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**main.js**

```
require.config({

    paths: {
        'angular': 'vendor/angular',
        'domReady': 'vendor/domready',
        'angularRoute': 'vendor/angular-route',
        'bootstrapCss': 'vendor/bootstrap-css'
    },

    shim: {
        'angular': {
            exports: 'angular'
        },
        'angularRoute': {
            deps: ['angular'],
            exports: 'angularRouter'
        }
    },

    deps: ['./bootstrap']
});
```

**bootstrap.js**

```
require([
    'angular', 
    'angularRoute', 
    'app',
    'services/loginSvc',
    'controllers/navCtrl',
    'controllers/homeCtrl',
    'controllers/loginCtrl',
    'routes'
    ], function (angular, angularRoute, app) {
    'use strict';

    angular.element(document).ready(function () {
        angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
    });

});
```

**app.js**

```
define([
    'angular',
     'angularRoute'
 ], function(angular, angularRoute) {

'use strict';

var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

return app;

});
```

**routes.js**

```
define(['app'], function(app) {
    'use strict';

    app.config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'js/views/home.html',
            controller: 'homeCtrl'
        })
        .when('/login', {
            templateUrl: 'js/views/login.html',
            controller: 'loginCtrl'
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: do you have any message in the broser console ?  Something like 'cannot find js/views/login.html?'. It seems that the file is not sent by your server, when accessing the '/' route you are sending the html file but not also the static dependencies. Let me know if you have any message in the console.

Comment: Nope, no errors, and I can see login.html in the network console when I navigate to example.com/#/login

Comment: Can you try programatically to move to /login? Something like `$location.path('/login')` from your homeCtrl?

Comment: @Zlatko I am doing that in navCtrl, when login() is called.  And still when I do the route change that way, I get the same result.

Answer (score 3):

I imagine you are typing the `/login` path directly in your browser. If you are typing the route in manually to your browser, when you type in `http://myapp.com/myapp/`, ng-route will follow the `/` route. However, if you type `http://myapp.com/myapp/login`, it will not follow the `login` route. This is because `ng-route` expects the route to come after a `#`.

Try typing `http://myapp.com/myapp/#/login`, obviously replacing the `myapp` parts with the appropriate path for your application.

Also, it might help to make a `/home` route, then use the `.otherwise()` function of `$routeProvider` to make that the default route that it loads. That way, if you attempt to hit a route that does not exist, it will default to the `/home` route, instead of showing you a blank template.

Here is how you would achive that:

```
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/home', {
        templateUrl: 'js/views/home.html',
        controller: 'homeCtrl'
    })
    .when('/login', {
        templateUrl: 'js/views/login.html',
        controller: 'loginCtrl'
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/home'
    });
});
```

**EDIT:**

Always use your browser's element inspector when you are using `ng-view`. The 'View Source' option in your browser will never show your loaded template code, because the actual source code of your page just contains `<div ng-view></div>`, and not the template code.

Comment: I was using the hashbang btw to navigate, didn't work.

Comment: Just tested again navigating to http://localhost:1337/#/login, navbar shows up, no errors in console, login.html shows up in network console, but does not get filled into ng-view

Comment: Try refreshing when you type it in direcly.

Comment: @Zlatko Tried refreshing just to take the suggestion, no luck there either.  I'm going to try Andrews updated suggestion and adding an otherwise call

Comment: @Andrew Mairose I added the otherwise, when I navigate to localhost:1337/#/login it is not redirecting to /home, any other path is.

Comment: @AndrewMairose <div class="container">
 <h1>Login page</h1>
</div>

Comment: What about `loginCtrl`? What does that look like?

Comment: @AndrewMairose define(['app'], function(app) {
 app.controller('loginCtrl',function($scope, loginSvc) {
  
 });
});

Comment: So just an empty controller.

Comment: And you have `loginSvc` defined?

Comment: @AndrewMairose I do. define(['app'], function(app) {
 app.service('loginSvc', function() {
  this.doStuff = function() {
   alert('doStuff called');
  }
 });
});

Comment: Okay, you've got me stumped then.

Comment: @AndrewMairose For once, I actually want to see an error message in my console...lol...

Comment: Instead of doing 'View Source', try using 'Inspect' or 'Inspect Element'. Even if your view loads successfully, it will not show up in 'View Source'. You can see this if you do 'View Source' on your `/home` route.

Comment: @AndrewMairose Lol, well I just removed the navbar on my page and I think it was putting the top of my view behind the navbar (since its fixed).  Because without the navbar I see it.

Comment: Haha classic. So there was no problem with your route all along :P

Comment: @AndrewMairose Nope hahah...sigh.  The thing that threw me off was that there was nothing in ng-view in view source :\  Anyways, thanks for helping.

Comment: Yup, always use 'Inspect' when using views. Your view code will never show up in 'View Source', because your source code doesn't have your template code in it. It just has `<div ng-view></div>`.

Answer (score 0):

My view actually was rendering.  But since I was using a fixed navbar, it was being displayed behind it (so it was invisible.)  I can add a margin to top of my ng-view div, really simple fix.